# Compare date with todays date 10 years ago

Tags: javascript, date

I want to check if the given date is higher than 10 years ago from today (so the person would have less than 10 years). I have searched many info with no possitive result.

**EDIT**: When I alert "objetoFechaNacimiento", if the user entered "22/1/2015", it alerts "Sat Oct 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200". This must be the problem...

This is what I got:

```
  var nacimiento = document.getElementById("fechaNacimiento").value;
  var objetoFechaActual = new Date();
  var objetoFechaNacimiento = new Date(nacimiento);
  var fechaMinima = objetoFechaActual.setYear(objetoFechaActual.getFullYear() - 10);
  var objetoFechaMinima = new Date(fechaMinima);

  if ( objetoFechaNacimiento.getTime() >= objetoFechaMinima.getTime() ) {
        alert("You can not be less than 10 years old.");
        return false;
  }
```

Comment: So what is the question. What you've got, should work perfect I think.

Comment: I am about to edit. That was not the problem.

Comment: I added an edit to the post,.

Comment: Instead of using setYear(), does setFullYear() help?

Comment: Sorry? It is getFeullYear, not setYear.

Comment: You have a problem because the date 22/1/2015 is interpreted as mm/d/yyyy, and because mm > 12, the remaining number of months are added to arrive at 1 October 2016. Check your regional/locale settings to see what is the date format on the machine & account you are running this on.

Comment: I'm refering to: `objetoFechaActual.setYear(...)`. I think you want to use `setFullYear()` here.

Comment: Worked with .setYear also!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just reformat the date to a valid format

Also when you create a minima date you can use setFullYear on that date instead of saving the result of a setDate

```js
const nacimiento = document.getElementById("fechaNacimiento").value;
const [dd, mm, yyyy] = nacimiento.split("/");
var objetoFechaNacimiento = new Date(yyyy, mm - 1, dd, 15, 0, 0, 0); // let's normalise at 15:00 to not run into midnight and daylight-saving

const objetoFechaMinima = new Date();
objetoFechaMinima.setFullYear(objetoFechaMinima.getFullYear() - 10);
objetoFechaMinima.setHours(15, 0, 0, 0); // also normalise;

console.log(objetoFechaNacimiento,objetoFechaMinima)


if (objetoFechaNacimiento.getTime() >= objetoFechaMinima.getTime()) {
  console.log("You can not be less than 10 years old.");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="fechaNacimiento" value="24/12/2020" />
```

Comment: I usually include "*Don't parse strings with the Date constructor, always parse them manually*". ;-)

Comment: I never allow users to enter dates directly. Give them dropdowns generated with valid dates or a date picker.

Answer (score 3):

In jsfiddle, I tried the following:

```
var curDate = new Date();
curDate.setFullYear(curDate.getFullYear() - 10);
alert(curDate);
```

When executed, it outputs `Mon Dec 12 2005 ...`

Answer (score 0):

I'd try the moment.js library http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/ Load it using require.js or just like that:

```
<script src="moment.js"></script>
```

and then something like

`var oneYearAgo = moment('2014-01-01T00:00:00.000').set('year',2013).format();`

or even better

`var oneYearAgo = moment(objetoFechaActual).subtract(1, 'years').format();`

In your case, probably even this should suffice:

`var oneYearAgo = moment().subtract(1, 'years').format();`

I really encourage you to use this lib for dates.